# Embedding Table from different website

Tags: html, embedding

I am trying to figure out the best way to capture a table from one website, and embed it on my own. I know this is kind of a no-no in terms of content creation. But I am simply hoping to just ensure that parents have quick access to their soccer schedule.

I need the schedule on [this website](http://www.pugetsoundpremierleague.com/_element_display/#%2F73228%2Fteams%2F87975495%2F78795886-87975596%2FTEAM.html%3Fdummy%3D1506108531442).

To be embedded into [this page](http://thurstoncountyunited.org/content/10963/G01-Navy-Justin-Hall).

You can see I tried already, but the content is not "live". I would prefer to have some type of iframe to just present the element with any changes that are made to the game times and especially the scores.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making an empty div on your page and populating it using jQuery load:

HTML:

`<div id="myTable"></div>`

Jquery:

`$('#myTable').load('http://www.pugetsoundpremierleague.com/_element_display/#%2F73228%2Fteams%2F87975495%2F78795886-87975596%2FTEAM.html%3Fdummy%3D1506108531442 #tblStandings1');`

Or you could use an iframe with scrollable="no" and position the page in the frame to just show the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the schedule to an online table and have the iframe code copied to your website.

I'd like to propose an alternative tool called RowShare, that allows an automatic update. I explained about this in an article that I wrote. Please feel free to take a look at it: https://www.rowshare.com/blog/en/2017/10/10/How-to-Embed-Tables-in-Your-Website

Astaeka